# Exclude rows containing a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
df.head()
applicationstartdate    segment fpd_30  fpd_90  fstpd_30
0   2020-01-01 00:04:10 3a.TBC Payroll with CB  0.0 0.0 0.0
1   2020-01-01 00:04:17 3a.TBC Payroll with CB  0.0 0.0 0.0
2   2020-01-01 00:14:25 1.TBC Payroll with CH (All) 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   2020-01-01 00:31:59 1.TBC Payroll with CH (All) 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   2020-01-01 00:41:49 1.TBC Payroll with CH (All) 0.0 0.0 0.
```

I want to exclude all the rows containing word "Payroll" in column "segment".

I tried:

```
df2 = df[~df["segment"].str.contains('Payroll')]
```

which yielded:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

You likely have NaNs in your column, you can use:

```
df2 = df[~df["segment"].fillna('').str.contains('Payroll')]
```

Or,f if you also want to filter out the NaNs:

```
df2 = df[~df["segment"].fillna('Payroll').str.contains('Payroll')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na = True` argument - because you are negating the condition and you want `NaN` to be filtered.

```
df2 = df[~df['segment'].str.contains('Payroll', na=True)]
```